# Converting a JSON object to array? Read description

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, node-mysql

my server upon request, serves JSON from a node mysql query, but only the names row. Example:

```
{
"Name": "Charles"
}, etc.
```

How can I, get the value of Name and put it into an array? say I have this,

```
  [
 {
  "Name": "Charles"
 },
 {
  "Name": "Alex"
 }
  ]
```

how can I get, Charles and Alex, into an array?

Like:

```
Names = ["Charles", "Alex]?
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be converting object to an array. This looks like a question of [how to parse json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object) and then how to map that json to [pluck a field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array) from all the objects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of the `map` function. The `map` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array. In your case, you need to select only the `Name`.

```js
var arr = [
 {
  "Name": "Charles"
 },
 {
  "Name": "Alex"
 }];
  
var names = arr.map(x=>x.Name)
console.log(names);
```

Comment: You sir, are wonderful. That is exactly what I was after! Thank you so much!

Comment: Just what I needed. Thanks!